# How to run a for loop inside a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am programming a WebExtension for Facebook which will invoke CSS based on their privacy settings.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Only Me']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr").css({"background-color": "lime"});
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='friends']").closest(".userContentWrapper._5pcr").css({"background-color": "cyan"});
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest("._2tdc").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Only Me']").closest("._2tdc").css({"background-color": "lime"});
    $("a[data-tooltip-content*='friends']").closest("._2tdc").css({"background-color": "cyan"});
```

However, I noticed that a different page layout are has a different class value that I need to invoke with CSS codes.

Is there any way to write a `for` loop inside a jQuery selector?

```js
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest("**For(a list of class name), loop through all of them)**").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```

I have tried using `$.each` jQuery, but I really don't have much of an idea after reading through the documents.

```
var obj = {".userContentWrapper._5pcr" , "._2dc"};

$.each(obj, function(index,element)){
      $("a[data-tooltip-content]").closest(obj).css({"background-color": "violet"});
      $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(obj).css({"background-color": "yellow"});
      $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Only Me']").closest(obj).css({"background-color": "lime"});
      $("a[data-tooltip-content*='friends']").closest(obj).css({"background-color": "cyan"});
}
```

Sample result ([original image link](https://s15.postimg.org/ft3sygk6j/Capture.png)):

[image: sample result]

Comment: [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: commas, if you need to select on multiple classes.

Comment: deleted~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as easy as storing all the class names in an array, and using a loop

```
var classses = ['.class1','.class2'];
for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++)
   $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(classes[i]).css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```

However, in general, multiple selectors can be separated with commas so this may also work.

```
$("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest('.class1, .class2')
                                      .css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it yourself

```
 $("a[data-tooltip-content*='Public']").closest(".class1, .class2, .class3").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```